# 3GModem NoSuch Port Execption

Tags: java, port, smslib, comm

I am using my 3G modem port in my SMSlib but my code is not detecting the port and is giving this error

```
try {   
    CommPortIdentifier portId = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("COM1"); 
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My modem port is COM1, but I haven't placed all "comm.jar" and "javax.comm.properties" and "win32com.dll" in respective directories

Comment: "this error"? What error?

Comment: javax.comm.NoSuchPortException
 at javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(CommPortIdentifier.java:105)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 2 JRE so i have copied my comm.jar .javax.comm.properties files in wrong jre/lib location.
But after copying files in both JRE's lib my problem has solved.